# Does Javascript have a contains function?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if it does or does not. Some sites show using a contains in javascript but when I try it does not work.

I have

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.split(';');

if (userAgent.contains("msie7") == true) {...}
```

I am trying to use the useragent to figure out if the user is running IE 8 in compatibility mode. So I want to check the userAgenet for msie7 & for the trident 4.0

So how could I check this array?

Comment: try this link http://forums.asp.net/post/4238818.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native `Array.prototype.contains` in ES v3 ( most JS implementations ). There is an Array.prototype.indexOf available in Mozilla/Firefox and other modern JS engines which choose to adopt it.

You can use the code below to implement it on browsers/engines that dont have it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/indexOf

Then after assigning it you can do `Array.prototype.contains = function(s) { return this.indexOf(s) !== -1 }`

Comment: Note that he does a `split`, so `userAgent` is an array, not a string. In either case, `indexOf` would work.

Comment: How can I make that clearer? I tried userAgent[] but it did not like that. Should I call it userAgentArray(what is bad practice I think in C# but not sure about javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` to get the index in the array which contains the element you're looking for. So you could rewrite your `if` statement like this:

```
if (userAgent.indexOf("msie7") > -1) {...}
```

---

Note that IE (at least IE6) doesn't support `indexOf` for arrays (it does work on strings though), but you could always write your own version:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.indexOf == 'undefined')
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
      if (this[i] == e)
        return i;
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: I probably will do that check to see if it is null. I don't support IE 6. I just come up with a reject sign.

Comment: Neither IE6, 7, or 8 support the method, it was recently implemented on the IE9 Platform Previews. I would recommend [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/indexOf) standards compliant version. It can take a second `fromIndex` argument, uses the strict comparison operator (`===`), etc...

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found out that jquery has a method called inArary and I used this. So I should not have to worry about compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can always roll out your own contains() which will work on Array objects on all browsers.

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (this[i] === obj) {
          return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Caveat:** "Extending the javascript Array object is a really bad idea because you introduce new properties (your custom methods) into for-in loops which can break existing scripts."

Better use the functions provided by a mainstream library such as jQuery.

Full discussion on this topic: [Javascript - array.contains(obj)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj/1342312#1342312)

Comment: "Caveat" - a good reason not to use `for-in` anyway, because many libraries will extend prototypes without you being aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

[Mootools](http://mootools.net/) is one library that can help you write better cross browser javascript. It augments javascript basic types([strings](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/String), [arrays](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Array), [numbers](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Number), etc) with convenient methods like 'contains'.

Or, you can implement it yourself as seen in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the array and test the string directly, like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('msie') != -1)
    // ...
```

Here's some [some information on indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf).